# Find parent node of a tree to create the shortest possible tree height

Tags: graph, tree, traversal, minimum-spanning-tree, depth-first-search

I have an undirected graph represented as an adjacency matrix of Euclidean weights. I'm using this to represent the minimum spanning tree for a larger complete graph.

What I want to find is the single node within the graph that, when used as the root node, creates the shortest possible tree height. What I've come up with is performing a depth-first traversal using every node as the root, and keeping track of the shortest height seen. Is there a faster way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic algorithms question.  What you're looking for is called the center of the tree, and it can be found using a simple iterative algorithm.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055964/centre-node-in-a-tree) has a great answer that explains how to do it.

Hope this helps!