# What's parent node and how to store it?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, binary-tree

I want to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055964/centre-node-in-a-tree) problem. Even IVlad answered the problem, I didn't understand what's parent node and what's child node. Can you explain me?

Answer (score 2):

Any node that has a child is called a parent node.  The descendents of the parent node are child nodes.  Most nodes can be parents of children and children of other parents.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to read the Tree datastructure before solving such a problem, the Parent and Child nodes are the alphabet of the Tree structure :
Read the Terminology of a [Tree (data structure)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_node) and [Binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree)