# All-pair shortest path for minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I am trying to solve an algorithm challenge about graphs, which I have managed to break down to the following: Given an undirected spanning tree, find the 2 leaves such that the cost between them is minimal.

Now I know of the Floyd Warshall algorithm that can find all-pair shortest paths with time complexity O(N^3) and space complexity O(N^2). The input of the problem is N = 10^5 so O(N^3) and O(N^2) are too much.

Is there a way to optimize space and time complexity for this problem?

Comment: for "minimum" cost between 2 vertices in an undirected minimum spanning tree, are the 2 vertices fixed? or are you trying to find 2 vertices with min cost?

Comment: As a minimum spanning tree is cycle-free, the path between any two nodes (without repetition of nodes) is uniquely determined.

Comment: @Codor , i am going forward and elaborate what you recommend as answer.

Comment: @PetarPetrovic Maybe my question was not clear enough. I meant find 2 (out of N) vertices such that the cost between them is minimal

Comment: Any explanation, on why my answer is downvoted .. :/

Comment: @goaty if u just need a pair of vertices, with minimum cost/distance, then the nodes which are connected by least weighted edge will be the answer.

Comment: @AmitKumar Sorry my mistake again. The requirement is about finding 2 LEAVES (i.e. among nodes that only have 1 connection)

Comment: @goaty, then my answer that i have written works, u just need to find all leaves nodes and run them as (a,b) in my algorithm

Answer (score 3):

As @Codor said, elaborating on that, in a MST there is only one unique path b/w any pair of nodes, and  same will be the shortest path.
In order to calculate shortest path b/w all pairs.
You can choose to follow this algorithm.

- You can basically choose find the root of the MST by constantly removing leaf   nodes till only one or two nodes are left .

  Complexity : [centre node in a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055964/centre-node-in-a-tree)
             this can be achieved in O(V) i.e linear time
- Choose one of them as root. Calculate distance of all the other nodes in respect to the root node using [Breadth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)(BFS).

  Complexity :  O(V+E) ~ O(V) in case of tree
- Now you can find distance b/w any pair of nodes call it a,b. Find its [least common ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor)(lcp).
  Then there are two case if

  1. lcp(a,b) = r (root of the tree).
     dis(a,b) = dis[a] + dis[b]
  2. lcp(a,b) = c ( which is not the root node)
     dis(a,b) = dis[a] + dis[b] - 2 * dis[c]

where dis(x,y) = distance b/w node x,y
and dis[x]  distance of node x from root node
  If implemented using Ranked Union Find

Complexity : O(h) , where h is height of the tree per pair of (a,b).
h = X/2, where X is the [diameter](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22855/algorithm-to-find-diameter-of-a-tree-using-bfs-dfs-why-does-it-work) of the tree.
So total complexity depends on the no. of leaf node pairs.

Comment: what is the time complexity of your algorithm?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic Adding the complexity part to the answer

Comment: In step 3 do you need to check for every pair of leaves?

Comment: Yep, but i think here memoization of states can help speed up the process and reduce redundant calculations